# clicking on the fragment invokes fragment behind

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

I have a really strange problem in my android app. The app contains several fragments and one of them consists a surfaceView. The most time changing to the fragment with the surfaceview works good but sometimes the replacement is unsuccessful. Then if I touch the surfaceview the fragment behind receives the touchevents and not the actual fragment.

But this only happens sometimes and not always. So it's really hard for me finding the reason.
Had anybody already the same or similar problem?

for replacing the fragment I use following code:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: I was just looking again for the reason, but I couldn't find.
But the problem isn't the surfaceview! sometimes the whole fragment doesnt react on touchevents, but the fragment behind!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your surface view has not been told to respond to touch events.

Try making it clickable, either with `android:clickable="true"` or `setClickable(true)`. That should prevent touch events from passing through the surface view to the fragment below.

Another trick I've used, for views that don't need to respond to touch, but do need to prevent events from going through them, is to add a touch listener and eat the event:

```
surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      return true; // true means the event has been processed
    }
});
```